# Multiple filters google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have two filters that check between a certain value range on my map that, when they are not between that range, turn the mark non visible. They both work fine seperatly but not combined, when the filter1 is activated it turns markers visible that were set non visible by filter2 for example. I've tried to stop this by checking if the marker is visible with getVisible() so it wouldnt turn on non-visible markers again but that prevents me from putting in a higher price range.

Any help would be highly appreciated, I've included a JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaj1b018/5/

```
function priceRange() {
  var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price1").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
  var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("price2").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
  infoWindow.close();

  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    mark = markers[i];
    if (parseInt(mark.prijs.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) > price1 && parseInt(mark.prijs.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) < price2 && mark.getVisible() == true) {
      mark.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      mark.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply combine check for both filters in the same button event handler (eg `oppervlakteRange`):

```
function oppervlakteRange(){
    var WoonOpp1 = document.getElementById("WoonOpp1").value;
    var WoonOpp2 = document.getElementById("WoonOpp2").value;
    var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("priceR1").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
    var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("priceR2").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);

    for(i=0;i<markers1.length;i++){
        mark = gmarkers1[i];

        if(parseInt(mark.woonop.replace(/\m2/g, ''), 10) > WoonOpp1 && 
           parseInt(mark.woonop.replace(/\m2/g, ''), 10) < WoonOpp2 &&
           parseInt(mark.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) > price1 && 
           parseInt(mark.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) < price2){
            mark.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            mark.setVisible(false);     
        }
    }
}
```

And for both upper value filter make sure that the highest possible value is `selected` by default:

```
<select id="priceR2">
    <option value="200.000">200.000</option>
    <option value="300.000">300.000</option>
    <option value="400.000" selected>400.000</option>
</select>

<select id="WoonOpp2" class="controls">
    <option value="50">50 m2</option>
    <option value="100">100 m2</option>
    <option value="150">150 m2</option>
    <option value="200" selected>200 m2</option>
</select>
```

Remove the `priceRange` method, as you do not need it any more.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaj1b018/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine both checks into a single function:

```
function filterMarkers() {
    var WoonOpp1 = document.getElementById("WoonOpp1").value;
    var WoonOpp2 = document.getElementById("WoonOpp2").value;
    var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("priceR1").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
    var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("priceR2").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);

    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        mark = gmarkers1[i];

        if ((parseInt(mark.woonop.replace(/\m2/g, ''), 10) > WoonOpp1 && parseInt(mark.woonop.replace(/\m2/g, ''), 10) < WoonOpp2) && (parseInt(mark.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) > price1 && parseInt(mark.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) < price2)) {
            mark.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            mark.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jaj1b018/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];

window.onload = function() {

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
  });

  // Our markers
  markers1 = [
    ['0', '100.000', 52.4357808, 4.991315699999973, '50m2'],
    ['1', '150.000', 52.4357808, 4.981315699999973, '75m2'],
    ['2', '200.000', 52.4555687, 5.039231599999994, '100m2'],
    ['3', '250.000', 52.4555687, 5.029231599999994, '125m2'],
    ['4', '300.000', 52.4335687, 5.029231599999994, '150m2']
  ];

  /**
   * Function to init map
   */

  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4357808, 4.991315699999973);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
      addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Function to add marker to map
   */

  function addMarker(marker) {
    var price = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1] + "</br>" + marker[4];
    var woonop = marker[4];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      price: price,
      position: pos,
      woonop: woonop,
      map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
      return function() {
        console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      };
    })(marker1, content));
  }

  // Init map
  initialize();

};

function filterMarkers() {
  var WoonOpp1 = document.getElementById("WoonOpp1").value;
  var WoonOpp2 = document.getElementById("WoonOpp2").value;
  var price1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("priceR1").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);
  var price2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("priceR2").value.replace(/\./g, ''), 10);

  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    mark = gmarkers1[i];

    if ((parseInt(mark.woonop.replace(/\m2/g, ''), 10) > WoonOpp1 && parseInt(mark.woonop.replace(/\m2/g, ''), 10) < WoonOpp2) && (parseInt(mark.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) > price1 && parseInt(mark.price.replace(/\./g, ''), 10) < price2)) {
      mark.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      mark.setVisible(false);

    }
  }

}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="priceR1">
  <option value="100.000">100.000</option>
  <option value="200.000">200.000</option>
  <option value="300.000">300.000</option>
  <option value="400.000">400.000</option>
</select>
<select id="priceR2">
  <option value="200.000">200.000</option>
  <option value="300.000">300.000</option>
  <option value="400.000">400.000</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="filterMarkers()" value="button" />
</br>
<select id="WoonOpp1" class="controls">
  <option value="50">50 m2</option>
  <option value="100">100 m2</option>
  <option value="200">200 m2</option>
  <option value="250">250 m2</option>
</select>
<select id="WoonOpp2" class="controls">
  <option value="50">50 m2</option>
  <option value="100">100 m2</option>
  <option value="150">150 m2</option>
  <option value="200">200 m2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="filterMarkers()" value="Klik hier" />
```